# Tree From List using FoldTree

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

I am trying to create a tree from a list.

I have written the function using foldl and foldr (latter not shown)

```hs
treeFromList l
    | null l = error "no elements in list"
    | otherwise = foldl insertIfAbsent (initTree (head l)) (tail l)
```

where the Tree DS is defined in a separate module as

```hs
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show

initTree x = (Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree)
```

and `treeFold` is manually written (not derived) as

```hs
foldTree f acc t
    | (empty t) = acc
    | otherwise = foldTree f outerVal (leftSub t) 
        where
        outerVal = f (value t) rightVal 
        rightVal = foldTree f acc (rightSub t)
```

After giving this some thought, I believe this cannot be done because of a type conflict. In theory, the tree would need to be build up in the accumulator while the list is constantly reduced/folded over.

On the contrary, I was able to convert to `foldl` version to `foldr`, and apparently `foldr` can be expressed using `foldTree`.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Note that `foldr` and `foldl` consumes lists to produce something, while `foldTree` consumes a tree to produce something. You can't replace one with the other, since they consume different things. (Unrelated: you should use pattern matching instead of guards and partial accessors. Functions like `head, tail, leftSub, rightSub, value` are dangerous since they crash your program on the wrong argument, and above they can be replaced by pattern matching -- e.g. `f [] = a ; f (x:xs) = use x xs` instead of `f l | null l = a | otherwise = use (head l) (tail l)`)

Comment: Thanks @chi! That is an erroneous assumption I was making, and I think you answered my question. Appreciate the pattern matching tip :)

Comment: @chi, `foldl` and `foldr` aren't just for lists. What do you mean? ZM-, note that `foldr` is the correct way to convert to a list in order. `foldl` is the correct way to convert to a list in reverse order. Doing it the other way around is usually less lazy and less efficient.

Comment: creating a tree from its enumeration list  is  nondeterministic -- there are many possible trees of different shapes housing the same list of elements. and -1 because the question is unclear, and the body contradicted the title.

Comment: @dfeuer The OP says they want to "create a tree from a list". I'm saying that in such case `foldTree` won't help, since it requires a tree. The fact that you can also `foldr,foldl` over any foldable is not really relevant here (unless I am missing something?).

Comment: @chi, I think you're right about that, but that your statement was potentially confusing. I know that you know at least as much as I do about this stuff; I just want to make sure communication is as clear as possible.

Comment: @chi the problem was that the very first line in the *body* said they wanted to make a list from a tree - the exact opposite from the title. so it would be relevant, if that was their intent (as I unfortunately assumed, at first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the different folds.

List-related folds `foldr` and `foldl` consume a list (or, more in general, a foldable) to produce something else (which might not be a list).

The tree-related fold `foldTree` consumes a tree to produce something else (which might not be a tree).

Hence, you can not switch from one to the other: if you only have a list as input, you do not have a tree to call `foldTree` with.